# Has anyone used Expression Engine with Open Saas to sync membership profiles to a cloud based CRM?

Tags: saas

I'm trying to sync new member registration and profile updates to a cloud based CRM.  Has anyone done this?  The CRM I'm using is Batchbook.  It uses Open Saas.

Answer (score 1):

I know someone has done an integration between [EE and Sugar](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sugar-integration) before, so it must be possible. Maybe you could contact the developers of that add-on and find out if they could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a little late, but I'd recommend looking at the Batchbook API docs: http://developer.batchblue.com/, plus their php library: https://github.com/batchblue/batchbook-php.

You could create an EE addon harnessing this library which would do what you needed (or you could get someone else to build it for you).